# How to get the start and end number of an ElementAnnotation?

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

The `ElementAnnotation` from the `analyzer` package is really not an element so I can't use `ParsedLibraryResult.getElementDeclaration` on it.

How can I know the offset and end of an `ElementAnnotation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get the node from the `ClassElement` and loop through its `childEntities` and manually find the nodes from the annotations.